# How to know whether a site is running in ATG?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

Is there any way to know that whether a site is running in ATG or not? For Ex: By viewing page source or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can start off by interrogating the `Response Headers` and look for the **X-ATG-Version**

```
X-ATG-Version:version=QVRHUGxhdGZvcm0vOS4yIFsgRFBTTGljZW5zZS8wIEIyQ0xpY2Vuc2UvMCAgXQ==
```

That normally indicates that a site is running ATG. That said, a lot of has been said about sites hiding their response headers for security purposes (as suggested in [RFC2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt)):

> Revealing the specific software version of the server may allow the
>      server machine to become more vulnerable to attacks against software
>      that is known to contain security holes. Implementers SHOULD make the
>      Server header field a configurable option.

If you don't already do this, you probably should.

Beyond the `Response Header`, the other tell tale sign that a site is using ATG is generally looking a the source code for the ever present hidden `formhandlers`

```
<input value="" type="hidden" name="/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler.someFormElement">
```